# Laravel 5 groupBy on collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to group Tasks by their due date to display in a list.

Wednesday 1 January 2015
  Task 1
  Task 2

etc

Here is the function:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $tasks = $user->tasks()->orderBy('due_at','ASC')->get();    
    $tasks_group = $tasks->groupBy('due_at');   
    return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks_group'));
}
```

But am receiving the error:

`array_key_exists()`: The first argument should be either a string or an integer

I have tried a few other ways but which were only returning one task per date.

Any help on what I am doing wrong here would be great.

Comment: Why don't you group by in builder? like this: `$tasks = $user->tasks()->groupBy('due_at')->orderBy('due_at','ASC')->get();`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, the way you suggest I only end up with 1 result per date, rather than multiple as per my question.

Comment: Just an update, I am using Laravel 5.1.1 and I know the groupBy method is different to previous versions: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0

Comment: If I do the following:
$tasks_group = $user->tasks()->get()->groupBy('due_at');

It works as expected and groups by the tasks name, but I need to group by the due at date field.

Comment: It looks like it isn't working as the due_at field is a Carbon date object... If I convert the due_at to a string it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager load the `tasks` relationship then do a `groupBy`.

Try the following codes:

```php
$user = Auth::user();

$user->load(['tasks' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('due_at', 'ASC');
}]);

$tasks_group = $user->tasks->groupBy('due_at');

return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks_group'));
```